# Strange data bytes found in UTF8 text file

Tags: text, unicode, utf-8, converters

I have been tasked to convert very old text file (comma separated table) to UTF-8 JSON.
This file contains a strange mix of legal UTF-8 and illegal data. There are plenty of correct `2-byte` and `3-byte` characters (with a `0x1110xxxx` kind of length prefix), most data is ASCII range `32-127`. Illegal bytes samples are `164, 188, 166, 178, 162, 180, 182, 170`.

Does it mean I deal with the custom encoding that I have to decrypt, or this could be some documented sort of encoding? Or I am understanding UTF-8 encoding incorrectly? Any insights?

I feel like this is a mix of UTF-8 and some old codepage.

**sample 1**

```
 22 2C 22 61 62 61 64 64 68 61 A2 22
```

This supposed to be the word "abaddhaṃ" in quotes, but as you see "ṃ" is A2

**sample 2** few bytes later looks like the same word in weird encoding

```
22 83 E0 86 E0 83 E0 8B E0 8B E0 93 E0 83 E0 B4 E0 22
```

**sample 3** few bytes later seem valid UTF-8:

```
EE 83 93 EE 82 97 │ EE 82 B2 EE 82 83
```

Comment: All of the above?! :-)

Comment: In UTF-8 Those bytes are subsequent bytes in a multibyte sequence. Show a real example.

Comment: added few samples from that file

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting data of unspecified origin.

Comment: You probably need a consultant, and you need to give them much more information than you have provided here. Give them access to all available information about the file – its origin, history, format (is it sure that it is plain text?), assumed use, etc., and of course the file itself. It can still be tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This file contains a strange mix of legal UTF-8 and illegal data

It may be impossible to recover the data reliably. Whilst something like `chardet` can be used to “guess the unknown encoding”, if you have a file where every *line* can be in a different encoding, there probably isn't enough data on every line to make a reasonable guess, even if you have standard encodings, which it looks like you don't.

> This supposed to be the word "abaddhaṃ" in quotes, but as you see "ṃ" is A2

There is no standard encoding which maps the byte 0xA2 to U+1E43 (Latin small letter ‘m’ with dot below). You may have mangled data or you may have a custom encoding, ie text that is only readable with a special font.

> EE 83 93 EE 82 97 │ EE 82 B2 EE 82 83

These are Private Use Area characters in the range U+E0xx. They have no standard meaning, and can again only be read correctly using a special font.

> 22 83 E0 86 E0 83 E0 8B E0 8B E0 93 E0 83 E0 B4 E0 22

These are similar Private Use Area characters, but encoded as UTF-16LE, inside normal non-UTF-16 quote marks and line endings. This is especially tricky because you can't tell for sure where the quotes and line endings are, since 0x22 and 0x0A are perfectly valid bytes to have inside a code unit.

It seems like this file is a bit of a crock, which probably isn't going to be at all usable without a lot of manual hacking. See if you can find out anything about its heritage, and if there's anything else around that consumes it. If there is a custom font around for its custom ‘visual encoding’ you might get closer.